# Nativescript 6 is very slow

Tags: angular, performance, nativescript

Our application was developed with nativescript 4. The change of rules at the level of the Android Store has forced us to go under nativescript 6. Since our application is very slow. For example the password entry sometimes freezes, there is latency when selecting in a menu. Has anyone meet the same issues and has a solution to improve the responsiveness of the application?

ps: we already use the following compile options: - env.aot --env.snapshot --env.uglify --production

thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

If you are using 6.1, adding the "markingMode: none" option to your project will probably speed the things up. The performance degradation is caused by changes in the V8 Garbage Collection routine. The markingMode: none option eliminates the overhead that NativeScript adds on top of the V8 algorithm and in fact it should be faster than what you used to experience in {N} 4.0.

Fore more information on how to enable this option, checkout this article: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/marking-mode-none#updating-an-app-or-a-plugin-to-support-markingmode-none

More context on the matter can be found [in the NativeScript Blog](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/markingmode-none-is-official-boost-android-performance-while-avoiding-memory-issues)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The performances have improved a little but I still have latencies when entering text. Do you have an idea of what can explain that ?

Comment: Not much can be said, without the actual application. Have you tried to profile the application? Do you have an idea where the bottleneck is?

Comment: No, I have no idea. We use TextField components.
The problem occurs especially when we entered text in a TextField, then we try to enter a text  in another TextField, the text freezes for a few seconds. It's very weird.

Comment: I'm dissapointed but stuck with NS - every major release has major breaking changes and just as slow if not slower. The NS guys are speading themselves thin by taking on more and more tech - but their core software is slow and broken - look at the number of issues on github.

Comment: Hey @dashman. Thanks for the feedback! The NativeScript Core team is always eager to address specific issues. With that said - if you experience any performance degradation, be sure to log a new issue and provide as much details as possible.

Regarding the breaking changes - well, that's the point of the major release. But I feel your pain - our goal moving forward would be to introduce breaking changes with limited effect for the developers.